# XCode autocomplete for UIView properties

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I've just noticed that XCode 6 adds to its autocomplete list 2 methods for every UIView property I have in my view controller.

Defining this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIview *myView;
```

Adding this to the editor's autocomplete list:

```
- (void) addMyViewObject:(<#object-type#> *)object
- (void) addMyView:(NSSet *)objects
```

What are those 2 methods for?